# Не знаю как исправить ошибку: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Недавно начал учить Java и постоянно сталкиваюсь с ошибками которых не могу исправить, поэтому прошу помощи. Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumaA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a: ");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter b: ");
        float b = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter c: ");
        double c = scanner.nextDouble();

        double adunare = a + b + c;
        double diferenta = a - b - c;
        double produsul = a * b * c;

        System.out.println("Suma este: " + amount);
        System.out.println("Diferenta este: " + diferenta);
        System.out.println("Produsul este: " + produsul);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Можно вводить данные только для первых двух переменных, после чего появляется ошибка:

```
Enter a: 5
Enter b: 4.4

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
at SumaA.main(SumaA.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: может у вас локаль стоит русская, попробуйте запятую как разделитель `4,4`

Comment: У вас точно для первых 2 данных? Даже если в введете 5 и потом снова 5 ?

Comment: tym32167 вы были правы, как только поставил запятую все компилировалось. Просто мелочь, но сколько времени понадобилось что бы найти решение

Comment: Dred, да можно было вводить все три данных типа int, и проблем не возникало